# Dark Theme for the Cardano Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request

Stack Exchange allows the creation of themes for individual sites however it doesn't provide anything by default beyond the default light theme for new sites.

Would it be possible to set up an additional dark theme (possibly a copy of the Stack Overflow dark theme)?

I know we are still in early days on the site however I feel this would be a useful Quality of Life feature.

Comment: Should be two separate questions and the icon/thumbnail is already asked here.

Comment: You can always use https://darkreader.org/ or a similar tool if you can't wait for the official dark theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not currently have any timeline to expand the dark mode features outside of Stack Overflow. You will, unfortunately, have to wait until our design team has ironed out all the details of per-site theming before it can be enabled across the network.

To clarify: we also do not allow sites to create their own themes on their own. Themes are created by our design team as a reward for graduating from beta, or due to the occasional site sponsorship.

Comment: It may be important to note that even sites graduated from beta might have to wait a while before getting a design because of backlog.